# How do I make my php app never ask for the Gmail API verification code?

Tags: gmail-api

I would like the app to work automatically, but while we're testing, if we spend the weekend without messing with it on Monday, the first thing the app does is:

Open the following link in your browser:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/(...)
Enter verification code:

Somewhere over the web I had seen once that it was necessary to bold the options in the code below; but not working as expected.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

// @return Google_Client the authorized client object
function getClient()
{
    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
                'proxy' => '<my_ip_proxy_pfsense>:<port>',
                'verify' => false,
        ]);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('RS Gmail Check API PHP');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
**$client->setAccessType('offline');**
// Using "consent" ensures that your application always receives a refresh token.
// If you are not using offline access, you can omit this.
**$client->setApprovalPrompt("consent");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth**
//
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
$client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

$tokenPath = '/opt/gmail-check/token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $authCode = $_GET['code'];
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($this->redirectUri, 
            FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

if(!file_exists(dirname($this->tokenFile))) {
                mkdir(dirname($this->tokenFile), 0700, true);
            }

            file_put_contents($this->tokenFile, json_encode($accessToken));
        }else{
            exit('No code found');
        }
        }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
// If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            } // */
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
$inboxMessage = [];

function decodeBody($body) {
    $rawData = $body;
    $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
    $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
    if(!$decodedMessage){
        $decodedMessage = FALSE;
    }
    return $decodedMessage;
}
$list = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user, ['maxResults' => 10, 'q' => $search]);
try{
        foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {

            $message_id = $mlist->id;
            $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
            $single_message = $service->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);
            $payload = $single_message->getPayload();
            $headers = $single_message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
            $snippet = $single_message->getSnippet();

            foreach($headers as $single) {

            if ($single->getName() == 'Subject') {

                $message_subject = $single->getValue();

            }
 else if ($single->getName() == 'Date') {

                $message_date = $single->getValue();
                $message_date = date('M jS Y h:i A', strtotime($message_date));
            }

            else if ($single->getName() == 'From') {

                $message_sender = $single->getValue();
                $message_sender = str_replace('"', '', $message_sender);
            }
        }

            $inboxMessage = [
                'messageId' => $message_id,
                'messageSnippet' => $snippet,
                'messageSubject' => $message_subject,
                'messageDate' => $message_date,
                'messageSender' => $message_sender
                ];

            // With no attachment, the payload might be directly in the body, encoded.
            $body = $payload->getBody();
            $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($body['data']);

            // If we didn't find a body, let's look for the parts
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                $parts = $payload->getParts();
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    if($part['body']) {
                        $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($part['body']->data);
                    }
                    // Last try: if we didn't find the body in the first parts,
                    // let's loop into the parts of the parts (as @Tholle suggested).
                    if($part['parts'] && !$FOUND_BODY) {


foreach ($part['parts'] as $p) {
                            // replace 'text/html' by 'text/plain' if you prefer
                            if($p['mimeType'] === 'text/html' && $p['body']) {
                                $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($p['body']->data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Update**: I spent this weekend doing some testing with another project using the Gmail API but based on the same code I am using in the service, and even though I spent more than 5 hours without running the application, no time was asked for the token more than once. . The most significant difference is that in the service GuzzleClient is configured to work with the proxy (which would be our pfsense firewall). Am I experiencing this token issue expiring at work because of the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are required to authenticate your app to obtain your [access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#2.-obtain-an-access-token-from-the-google-authorization-server.)
- This is necessary the very first time you run your app or if you change your scopes
- Your access token will expire after a certain time
- In order to avoid re-authentication when your access token expires, you need to incorporate a [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#4.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.) into your app
- A refresh token will refresh your access your access token automatically every time before the latter expires
- You will not be prompted each time to re-authenticate
- [Further reading](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/authorizing)

How to incorporate the refresh token into your APP

Follow the [Google API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) for PHP. Sample:

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$user = 'me';
$results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
  print "No labels found.\n";
} else {
  print "Labels:\n";
  foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
    printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

After you provided your complete code, I can see that in addition to the required authorization flow, you have the following spare lines:

```
else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $authCode = $_GET['code'];
            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($this->redirectUri, 
            FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

if(!file_exists(dirname($this->tokenFile))) {
                mkdir(dirname($this->tokenFile), 0700, true);
            }

            file_put_contents($this->tokenFile, json_encode($accessToken));
        }else{
            exit('No code found');
        }
        }
```

So, e.g. the lines

```
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
```

create an authorization URL and prompt for authentication, however mind that in the

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
```

you are doing the same again - this would explain why you are prompted for authentication for often than expected.

Also, you have the lines

```
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

twice.

If you remove the spare code and erase your token file (to trigger new authentication flow), your problem should be solved.

Comment: My code was based on 'quickstart ṕhp gamil api' and already contains the lines that update the token. The code may be running at an interval that has a period after the token expires (for example: the token expires at 17:57 and the code runs at 6:00 pm, within a 60-minute interval). Not sure if that is it. But if so, and the code is to be executed every one hour, the refresh time must be greater than 60 minutes; How would I then redefine this time?

Comment: Can you provide your whole code, including the acquisition of token? If you have a refresh token incorporated, your access should never expire.

Comment: token.json:

{"access_token":"ya(...)","expires_in":3600,"scope:"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/gmail.readonly","token_type":"Bearer","created":1577993881}

I changed the 3600 to 7200 but when upgrading back to 3600; obviously that's not how I change this time, what would it be like?

Comment: You cannot change 3600 to a higher values, since 1 h is the maximum time after which an access token expires and it is not possible to incorporate a refresh time bigger than one hour. As I mentioned before, the solution is to incorporate a REFRESH token into your code that will refresh your access token automatically when necessary.  In my code, this is incorporated by `if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {...`

Comment: You say that your code also contains the lines that update the token. Can you edit your answer and provide your complete code including those lines, so I can have a look if there is something missing?

Comment: I edited the question, almost all the code is now showing, except for the part that filters what I want in emails.

Comment: I'm betting my chips that the getRefreshToken method, on the line '$ client-> fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken ($client-> getRefreshToken ());', is not going through the proxy, so it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for providing your code, the problem I see is that you have some additional unnecessary lines - some of them double. For visibility reasons I will include them in my answer.

Comment: The code is as you suggested, I excluded all the "spare" part; but the token continues to expire. I am watching the pfsene squid in real time and nothing appears when requesting the token occurs; that is, is not making refresh request by squid (which should pass, even if I saw a denied there)

Comment: After implementing the changes, did you delete the old token file on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I had deleted it. But I managed to solve the problem by copying all the test project files from my personal notebook, where I did without a firewall, to the company's production machine, and it's not expiring now! I believe something was missing from the installation of the issues due to the firewall. Something (some file, some dependency, it will be hard to figure it out, the mystery will remain) from the upgrade part was missing. I will accept your answer because the problem, it seems, was due to installation, and possibly the cause was firewall blocking.